# Count downloads without `echo file_get_contents($file)`?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, download

I am now having download links on my server that directly points to files. I have a set of quite complicated rewrite rules but they don't affect what I am asking for.

What I want to do is to count the number of downloads. I know I could write a PHP script to echo the content and with a rewrite rule so that the PHP script will process all downloads.

However, there are a few points that I am worried about:

1. There is a chance that some dangerous paths (e.g. `/etc/passwd`, `../../index.php`) will not be blocked due to carelessness or unnoticed bugs
2. Need to handle `HTTP 404 Not Found` response (and others) in the script which I prefer letting Apache handle them (I have an error handler script that rely on server redirect variables)
3. HTTP headers (like content type or modified time) may not be correctly set
4. <s>Using a PHP script doesn't usually allow `HTTP 304 Unmodified` response so that browser caching will be useless, and re-download can consume extra bandwidth</s> Actually I can check for that, but would require some more coding and debugging.
5. PHP script uses more processing power than directly loading the file directly by Apache

So, I would like to find some other ways to perform statistics. Can I, for example, make Apache trigger a script when certain files (in certain directories) are being requested and downloaded?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple log processing script? Something like `awstats`?

Comment: point 4 is false. there's no reason php can't check for if-modified-since in the request and respond appropriately.

Comment: @MarcB well perhaps that's true but it would require some coding (and debugging)... anyway I still have other concerns so I would still like another way.

Comment: @arkascha that *can* be a way but not convenient. I prefer counting with a script real time in MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: Ok, if you really need a realtime evaluation, then evaluate the log files in realtime.

Comment: @arkascha If I really adopt this method I will need a service in background. Also, log files contains many other useless information. So I still don't think parsing log files is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but in the spirit of using the right tool for the job you could easily use Google Analytics (or probably any other analytics package) to track this. Take a look at https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1136922.

Edit:

It would require the ability to modify the vhost setup for your site, but you could create a separate apache log file for your downloads. Let's say you've got a downloads folder to store the files that are available for download, you could add something like this to your vhost:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/downloads/.+$" download
LogFormat "%U" download-log
CustomLog download-tracking.log download-log env=download
```

Now, any time something is requested from the /downloads/ folder, it will be logged in the download-tracking.log file.

A few things to know:

- You can have as many SentEnvIf lines as you need. As long as they all set the download environment variable, the request will be logged to the CustomLog
- The LogFormat I've shown will log only the URI requested, but you can easily customize that to log much more than just the URI, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat for more details.
- If you're providing PDF files, be aware that some browsers/plugins will make a separate request for each page of the PDF so you would need to account for that when you read the logs.

The primary benefit of this method is that it does not require any coding, just a simple config change and you're ready to go. The downside, of course, is that you'd have to do some kind of log processing. It just depends what is most important to you.

Another option would be to use a PHP script and the [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) function. This makes it much easier to log requests to a database, but it does come with the other issues you mentioned earlier.

There are ways to pipe Apache logs to MySQL, but from what I've seen it can be tricky. Depending on what you're doing, it may be worth the effort... but then again it might not.

Comment: That means monitoring download links? Not something I would like as links are sometimes linked externally. And this would require Google Analytics. (I will be giving Google information for them to make money?)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Apache log files.

Comment: As my comments on the question points out, this is not a solution that I desire.

Answer (score 0):

Apaches [mod_lua](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_lua.html) probably is the most general, flexible and effective approach to hooking own code into the request processing inside apache. Usually you chose that language for the task that offers the most direct approach. And lua is much better in teracting with c/c++ than anything else.

However there certainly are other strategies, so be creative. Two things come to my mind immediately:

- some creative use of PAM if you are under some sort of unix like system: configure some kind of dummy authentication requirement and setup PAM for processing. Inside the PAM configuration you can do whatever you like. The avantage: you get requests and can filter yourself what to count and what not. You have to make sure the PAM response does not create a valid session though, so that you really get a tick for each request done by a client, not only the first one.
- there are other apache modules that allow to do request processing. Have a look at the [forensic module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_forensic.html) or the [external filter module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html). Both allow to hook external logic into request processing. You will need cli based php configured for that.

Comment: What if I want a solution in PHP?

Comment: @AlvinWong: I added some additional creative starting points to the answer. But I suggest you start exploring yourself, it is actually fun to find elegant and creative solutions for such questions!